# plot label in matplotlib after xy plotting python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, label

I need to create my line label outside of the plotting function for my coordinate points. I have a list of lists to loop through to create separate lines for each phase of test data:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,8.5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)    
list_of_x_points = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],...]
    list_of_y_points = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],...]

for i in range(len(list_of_x_points)):
    ax.plot(list_of_x_points[i], list_of_x_points[i], linecolor = "b" , linewidth = 1, linestyle = 'dashed'))
```

If I have the label inserted after `linestyle`, the label will print each time the loop happens. I only want it to print once. I've tried `ax.legend(['Line Name'])` after and outside of the for loop, but it doesn't work. How can I assign a label to the line in the graph? Graph looks like this:

[image]

Comment: what is `ax` here. make it  [Minimal, Complete and Verfiable Example(**MCVE**)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `ax.legend(['Line Name'])` should work if you have labeled the data previously like you said (it's not reflected in the code, so one cannot be certain what you actually did. Always show the actual code, don't describe it!).

Comment: `ax = fig.add_subplot(111)` i'll edit the question

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest what do you mean label it previously?

Comment: imho it does not matter if previously a label was inserted in the plot command or not.
After running your code I can tell, `ax.legend['Label name']` definitely works.
The only error message I received was `AttributeError: Unknown property linecolor`, so I'd recommend to leave this away, only `"b"`at this place is enough here, because plot expects a format-string here.

Perhaps this error was the only problem for you, too, so that the last command to build a legend was not executed?

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out, I created a testable version of my code, and the `ax.legend()` worked.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,8.5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)    
list_of_x_points = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
list_of_y_points = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]]

for i in range(len(list_of_x_points)):
    ax.plot(list_of_x_points[i], list_of_x_points[i], "-b" , linewidth = 1, linestyle = 'dashed')
ax.legend(['Print this'])
plt.show()
```

Still not understanding what was going wrong with my original code, I kept looking and found an obvious answer:

```
for i in range(len(list_of_x_points)):
    ax.plot(list_of_x_points[i], list_of_x_points[i], "-b" , linewidth = 1, linestyle = 'dashed', label = "Print this" if i == 0 else "")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

I don't know if this is considered bad practice, so I would like some feedback regarding back, but it did work.